# Recursive makefiles within vim

Tags: vim, g++, makefile

My c++ project consists of multiple directories each with their own makefile. One level up I also have a top level makefile which calls the other ones in order.

From within vim I want to make either the top level makefile or one the sub ones. I want to see my errors within vim, pressing ENTER on a line to jump to a source code line.

This works using

`make | copen`

but only one directory at a time. The file name listed in the error window is just a name, no path. If you try to build the top level makefile and press ENTER on a file name / line number, it does't know the path to the file.

Is there a way around this? I would like to build the top level makefile from within vim and no matter what directory the errors are in to jump to the correct file. The problem may be that g++ only outputs the name of the file, not the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'errorformat'` has a mechanism built in for that; from `:help errorformat`:

> Some compilers produce messages that consist of directory names that have to
>   be prepended to each file name read by %f (example: GNU make).  The following
>   codes can be used to scan these directory names; they will be stored in an
>   internal directory stack.                 *E379*
>     %D      "enter directory" format string; expects a following
>               %f that finds the directory name
>     %X      "leave directory" format string; expects following %f
>
> When defining an "enter directory" or "leave directory" format, the "%D" or
>   "%X" has to be given at the start of that substring.  Vim tracks the directory
>   changes and prepends the current directory to each erroneous file found with a
>   relative path.  See |quickfix-directory-stack| for details, tips and
>   limitations.

So, you need to get your Makefile to output these "change directory" messages, and make sure they are parsed correctly via your `'errorformat'` setting.

Comment: I need to get comfortable with the errorformat thing in general so currently looking for something good to read. Started to read the vim help and got pretty lost very soon. I'll report back when I understand the stuff.

Comment: If you don't want to output the messages yourself, `make -w` does it.

Answer (score 0):

You could give Vim a custom command to execute with `:make`:

```
:set makeprg=make\ -f\ /path/to/your/toplevel/makefile
```

Comment: I try this, then I open one of the sub files and `make | copen'. The error list contains a filename without a directory so it doesn't open the existing file, but a new empty one instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map in your vim to the following

```
!find .. -type d -exec make -C {} \;
```

something like:

```
map  <F12>    <esc>:!find .. -type d -exec make -C {} \;<cr>
```

I believe you should still see the errors in the :clist.

If you want to run the upper level make file you can do something like:

```
:make -C .. | copen
```